# Can I use Windex on my gorilla glass laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, display

I am just wondering if I am able to use windex on my laptop screen. I know that it has alcohol in it and that substance should be avoided like the plague when cleaning devices. But I am confused, will the alcohol in the windex still cause damage to my laptop screen even though it is gorilla glass? If so what damage could it do, and what alternatives are there to cleaning a screen like this.

I have the Dell XPS 15.

Comment: alcohol is fine. You're confusing it with ammonia, which damages screens, and windex contains ammonia. The safest option is using a cleaner or wipe designed for laptop screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alcohol is absolutely fine. Most cleaners as-is include some level of alcohol, it's the reason why they evaporate quickly. I use it all the time on external and **internal** components. You must be thinking of ammonia or acetone. These should **definitely** be avoided. Windex general does contain ammonia but it's diluted by a lot of other solvents.

To answer your question, Windex will be just fine, I assure you. The exception being that it can be more runny/watery than alcohol so make sure to spray a cloth first or at least, don't over due it. Seeing as how you can obviously damage a keyboard with too much exposure to liquid.

Alternatives? Wipes specifically designed for LCD/screen cleaning.

Comment: What do think about Journeyman Geek's comment on the ammonia in Windex, which isn't good for screens? Is it still fine?

Comment: Yup, I commented on that. There is small amounts of ammonia in Windex, depending on what kind you have, but nothing near what I would consider harmful much less worth mentioning. I only do so out of technicality plus the ammonia in Windex is diluted with several other chemicals, it's no big deal. I've used 409/Windex on touchscreens/laptops/screens all the time at work when we are out of wipes or LCD screen spray. Spray away, spray away.

Comment: Thanks for that BiTinerary. I have been worried about using it for sometime now due to some of the stuff I have read online. Big thanks for clearing up the ambiguity! :)

Comment: I've seen window cleaner spray take the coating off monitors before now. Wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 1):

Safe alternative - two microfibre cloths; one wet then squeezed as dry as you can, one dry.

Wipe over with the wet, wait 1 minute, once more with the wet, then a quick polish with the dry.

No chemicals, no harsh abrasives.
You can also do the TV & all the mirrors in the house while you're at it ;-)